# Referring to one's own examples

Tags: numbering, examples

I have created numbered examples to illustrate concepts in my project. I have used this

```
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
```

thus far. Is there a way I can refer to them so they appear as **{Ex 2.1}** and LaTeX to keep track of the numbering?

Refer me to a similar question if one is available but I am almost certain there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that your example has label `ex21` and you have defined

```
\newcommand{\exref}[1]{\textbf{\{\ref{#1}\}}}
```

then `\exref{ex21}` does it.

Example

```
\begin{exmp}
\label{ex21}
Text of your example
\end{exmp}
```

And then: we show it in `\exref{ex21}`.

Comment: I'm sure you're answer will work but I am very new to latex. Would you please enter some further details. What I have been doing is,

I have 
\begin{exmp}
My example goes here
\end{exmp}

Comment: @KaneBlackburn I have just extended my answer.

Comment: Fantastic completely clear now!